# Copy and paste Column A based on result of Column AP

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon,

I am a completely new to the world of VBA. I have a workbook that is used to record risks, I have a sheet called RiskRegister that holds all the data on each of the risks recorded. I also have a summary tab which uses the ID from the risk register sheet and uses vlookup formulas to copy the relevant fields across to the summary sheet. What I need my update macro to do is search through column AP on sheet AP to search for "V High", if it finds a match I need to copy the value of column A from that row into the next available row on column A of sheet CSR Risk Report. I have found the below code, but when I run it I get run time error 424 object required. Can someone please advise where I have gone wrong, or if there is a better way to achieve this task?

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

        Dim tValue As String
Dim dValue As String

'Get last row value of sheet RiskRegister
a = Worksheets("RiskRegister").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    'If Value = "V High" then copy the value in column A into coloumn 1 of "CSR Risk Report"
    If Worksheets("RiskRegister").Cells(i, 42).Value = "V High" Then

        tValue = Worksheets("RiskRegister").Cells(i, 1).Value.Copy
        Worksheets("CSR Risk Report").Activate

        'Get last row of "CSR Risk Report" and paste the value in last row of column A
        b = Worksheets("CSR Risk Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        dValue = Worksheets("CSR Risk Report").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        dValue = tValue

        Worksheets("RiskRegister").Activate

    End If

Next

' Not sure what this is
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

I will also need to loop through results for "High" and then "Medium", I was planning on simply repeating the if loop with the new search criteria. I hope this will paste it in the correct priority order i.e. V high -> High -> Medium

Kind Regards

Adam

Comment: Which line errors? Presumably `tValue = Worksheets("RiskRegister").Cells(i, 1).Value.Copy`? You can't assign a variable and then copy, you either copy the range or assign the value and insert it into another range.

Comment: Also read up on how to avoid Select/Activate, which slows down code, and you could use the Find method rather than a loop, which also makes your code more efficient and quicker.

Comment: to process multiple conditions use elseif and else, but yes if you want all the V High processed then all of the High Processed then Medium, etc you have several options, run through each condition as you are saying or the faster method with only one loop, is to sort that Risk Register sheet by its condition (assign a column for numerical, V high = 3, High = 2, Medium  = 1 and so forth, then sort the range on that column before you start this process, then the CSR will be in order the way you speak of and you will only run through one loop.

Comment: Just saw an answer below that uses an array to order the conditions for you in one loop, pretty clever, might be advanced but you can decipher whats going on (depends on how familiar you are with arrays).

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I ended up solving the query using HackSlash's method and adding a custom sort at the end of the loop. This was my first attempt at a piece of vba and it opened my eyes up to how much I do not know about excel! Again, thank you all for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up: declare "Option Explicit"

Then declare your variables

No we can see that you are attempting to assign a method ".copy" to a string variable. ".copy" method puts the value in to the clipboard, not a variable.

Then you do the same thing below, attempting to put method ".select" in to a string...

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim tValue As String
Dim dValue As Range

'Get last row value of sheet RiskRegister
Dim a As Long
a = Worksheets("RiskRegister").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To a

    'If Value = "V High" then copy the value in column A into coloumn 1 of "CSR Risk Report"
    If Worksheets("RiskRegister").Cells(i, 42).Value = "V High" Then

        tValue = Worksheets("RiskRegister").Cells(i, 1).Value
        'Worksheets("CSR Risk Report").Activate

        'Get last row of "CSR Risk Report" and paste the value in last row of column A
        Dim b As Long
        b = Worksheets("CSR Risk Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set dValue = Worksheets("CSR Risk Report").Cells(b + 1, 1)
        dValue = tValue

        'Worksheets("RiskRegister").Activate

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

**NOTE:** "Application.CutCopyMode = False" clears the clipboard. You would only need that if you were using .copy and .paste methods. If we use variables and values directly then we don't need this.

Comment: I thought ´dValue´ was a range... just saw you updated it! :D nice

Answer (score 2):

Building on comments above, try this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim tValue As String
Dim dValue As String
Dim a As Long, i As Long, b As Long, r As Range, v, j As Long

v = Array("V High", "High", "Medium")

With Worksheets("RiskRegister")
    'Get last row value of sheet RiskRegister
    a = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
        Set r = .Range(.Cells(2, "AP"), .Cells(a, "AP")).Find(What:=v(j), Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                                         MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not r Is Nothing Then
            tValue = .Cells(r.Row, 1).Value
            'Get last row of "CSR Risk Report" and paste the value in last row of column A
            b = Worksheets("CSR Risk Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets("CSR Risk Report").Cells(b + 1, 1).Value = tValue
        End If
    Next j
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy cells and change activation between your worksheets - you also don't need to check for the last row (variable b) every single time you update it you can just add 1

**To be honest, it sounds like you just need to arrange things with a filter** but for sake of code answer try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim WSA As Worksheet
Dim WSB As Worksheet

Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim i As Long

Set WSA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RiskRegister")
Set WSB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CSR Risk Report")

'Get last rows
a = WSA.Cells(WSA.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
b = WSB.Cells(WSB.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If WSA.Cells(i, 42).Value = "V High" Then

        b = b + 1
        WSB.Cells(b, 1).Value2 = WSA.Cells(i, 42).Value2

    End If

Next

End Sub
```